# How to rename file extension in Jest?

Tags: angular, reactjs, jestjs

I need to test my code. We are in the middle of a migration from Angular 1.5 to React, our Angular files extension is .jsa and our React file extension is .js.

Problem: as expected, Jest doesn't understand the file extension .jsa.

here is my jest config in the package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverage": false,
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./jest.setup.js",
    "testMatch": [
      "**/app/**/*.spec.js"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(svg)$": "<rootDir>/test/svg.mock.js",
      "^Store/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/app/webapp/modules/store/$1",
      "^App/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/app/$1",
      "Common(.*)$": "<rootDir>/app/common/$1",
      "ProfileCapture(.*)$": "<rootDir>/app/profile_capture/$1",
      "^Helpers/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/app/common/helpers/$1",
      "PageKit": "<rootDir>/app/common/components/PageKit"
    },
    "verbose": false
  }
```

I've tried to add a line moduleNameMapper:

```
"^App/(.*)[\\.]jsa$": "<rootDir>/app/$1.js"
```

But it seems to be conflicting with

```
"^App/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/app/$1"
```

What is wrong in my regex(s)?